# Maintaining order of extracted patterns from strings in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract a pattern from a string, but am having difficulty maintaining the order. Consider:

```
library(stringr)
string <- "A A A A C A B A"
extract <- c("B","C")
str_extract_all(string,extract)

[[1]]
[1] "B"

[[2]]
[1] "C"
```

The output of this is a list; is it possible to return a vector that maintains the original ordering, ie that `"C"`precedes `"B"` in the string? I've tried many options of `gsub` with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: `str_extract_all(string,paste0("\\b(?:", paste(extract, collapse="|"), ")\\b")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following regexp:

```
str_extract_all(string,"[BC]")
## [[1]]
## [1] "C" "B"
```

or more generally:

```
str_extract_all(string, paste(extract, collapse = "|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string <- "A A A A C A B A B"
extract <- c("B","C")

inds = unlist(sapply(extract, function(p){
    as.numeric(gregexpr(p, string)[[1]])
}))
sort(inds[inds > 0])
# C B1 B2 
# 9 13 17
```